# The balance() function is not working properly

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

In the bf() function I have tried to assign the balance factors to every node of my **AVL tree**. The first iteration when I call the function from main() function by passing tree works perfectly. But the after first recursion the balance() function is not responding and code doesn't proceeds further.
I have printed *'g'* and *'m'* letters to know upto where the code is working.
*'g'* only gets printed once when I call from main function but *'m'* not even once.

```
int balance(struct node *tree)
{
  int lh,rh;
  if(tree==NULL)
  return 0;
  else
  {
  lh=balance(tree->left);
  rh=balance(tree->right);
  return (lh+1)-(rh+1);
  }
  }

void bf(struct node *tree)
      {
        tree->bfactor=balance(tree);  //not proceeding after this step after first recursion.
        printf("g");
        bf(tree->left);
        printf("m");
        bf(tree->right);
      }
```

Comment: So what should `bf` do for an empty tree? (Once you answer this, try to make your algorithm.more efficient, it is at O(n^2) now which makes the entire thing useless).

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent bbefore every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) function names should be 'active' and indicate what the function does.  'bt' is meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: strongly suggest using a debugger (like `gdb`) to step through your program to determine where the program is not doing what you expect

Comment: rather than posting some code snippet.  post a [mcve] that shows the problem, so we can help you debug it.

Comment: It is a minimal and complete code. The full version of the code is of 212 lines.

Comment: after I pass tree->left in the balance function it doesn't proceeds after that. It just sticks somewhere.

Comment: @n.m. thanks for pointing out the mistake. I just did some changes and it works perfectly fine now. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The bf() function should only work if the tree is not equal to NULL. Just adding this condition to bf() function makes it work perfectly fine.

```
void bf(struct node *tree)
  {  
       if(tree!=NULL)
       {
           tree->bfactor=balance(tree);
           bf(tree->left);
           bf(tree->right);
       }
  }
```